# End line takes large portion of time in Matlab profiler

Tags: matlab, profiler

I'm attempting to speed up my code and noticed in profiler a end line is taking up a significant portion of total run time. Any thoughts on why this would be and/or how to make my current code more efficient? The for loop is written to determine the distance (number of columns/rows away) of any non-zero number from the closest zero. Thanks for any help!

[Profiler Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zia7p.jpg)

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Because that's the point where it actually does the I/O. I/O wanders off through nine yards of system functions, including painting to the screen if that's where the data is going.